# Application user and relation between other tables (entities)

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to associate Application user with UserTask application table. But I get the bellow error

InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'ApplicationUser.UserTask' of type 'UserTask'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

I use NetCore 2.0.3

```
public class UserTask
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserTaskID { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OwnerUserID")]
        public string TaskOwnerId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ExecutorUserID")]
        public string TaskExecutorId { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser OwnerUserID { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ExecutorUserID { get; set; }
    }


 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
       [ForeignKey("UserTaskID")]
       public int UserTaskID { get; set; }

       public UserTask UserTask { get; set; }
    }
```

**controler**

```
public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["TaskOwnerId"] = new SelectList(_userManager.Users.ToList(), "Id", "Name");

            ViewData["TaskExecutorId"] = new SelectList(_userManager.Users.ToList(), "Id", "Name");

            return View();
        }

        // POST: UserTasks/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("UserTaskID,Description,TaskOwnerId,TaskExecutorId")] UserTask userTask)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(userTask);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["TaskOwnerId"] = new SelectList(_userManager.Users.ToList(), "Id", "Name", userTask.TaskOwnerId);

            ViewData["TaskExecutorId"] = new SelectList(_userManager.Users.ToList(), "Id", "Name", userTask.TaskExecutorId);

            return View(userTask);
        }
```

**and the view**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TaskOwnerId" class="control-label"></label>
                 <select asp-for="TaskOwnerId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TaskOwnerId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TaskExecutorId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="TaskExecutorId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TaskExecutorId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TaskOwnerId" class="control-label"></label>
                 <select asp-for="TaskOwnerId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TaskOwnerId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TaskExecutorId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="TaskExecutorId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TaskExecutorId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could you help me?

Comment: did you add UserTask in DB context?

Comment: Yes, I did public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<UserTask> UserTask { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<UserTask>().ToTable("UserTask");
        }

Comment: I believe you are trying to make one-to-one relationship between ApplicationUser and UserTask table. Did you run the migration?

Comment: Yes, 
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'ApplicationUser.UserTask' of type 'UserTask'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'ApplicationUser.UserTask' of type 'UserTask'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using

Comment: 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.PropertyMappingValidationConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)

Comment: It will be one to many relationship: one user to many tasks

Comment: Check the below answer.

Comment: I got an error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS1061 'UserTask' does not contain a definition for 'ApplicationUser' and no extension method 'ApplicationUser' accepting a first argument of type 'UserTask' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) UserTaskTest C:\Users\lukas\source\repos\UserTas‌​kTest\UserTaskTest\D‌​ata\ApplicationDbCon‌​text.cs 23 Active

Comment: public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<UserTask> UserTask { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
           builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
          .HasOne(a => a.UserTask)
          .WithOne(b => b.ApplicationUser);
        }
   
    }

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'UserTask' does not contain a definition for 'ApplicationUser' and no extension method 'ApplicationUser' accepting a first argument of type 'UserTask' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) UserTaskTest C:\Users\lukas\source\repos\UserTaskTest\UserTaskTest\Data\ApplicationDbContext.cs 23 Active

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
public class UserTask
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserTaskID { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser {get; set; }
}
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public ICollection<UserTask> UserTask { get; set; }
}
```

And in ApplicationDbContext class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasMany(a => a.UserTask)
    .WithOne(b => b.ApplicationUser);}
```

Comment: I got an error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'UserTask' does not contain a definition for 'ApplicationUser' and no extension method 'ApplicationUser' accepting a first argument of type 'UserTask' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) UserTaskTest C:\Users\lukas\source\repos\UserTaskTest\UserTaskTest\Data\ApplicationDbContext.cs 23 Active

Comment: I need task owner and task executor. When I leave the fields without foreign keys I get error while migration The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined. 

public class UserTask
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserTaskID { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string TaskOwnerId { get; set; }

        public string TaskExecutorId { get; set; }


        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    }

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is two-fold:

1. You only have one navigation property for `UserTask` on `ApplicationUser`. There's two different navigation properties for `ApplicationUser` on `UserTask`, EF cannot map both relationships to just one foreign key on the other side, so if you have two navigation properties on one side, you need two on the other as well. For example:

   ```
   public UserTask OwnedUserTask { get; set; }
   public UserTask ExecutedUserTask { get; set; }
   ```
2. Given that there's two relationships to the same entity, EF doesn't know which one on `UserTask` to map to which one on `ApplicationUser`, so you'll have to configure this:

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
           .HasOne(x => x.OwnedUserTask)
           .WithOne(x => x.OwnerUser);

       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
           .HasOne(x => x.ExecutedUserTask)
           .WithOne(x => x.ExecutorUser);
   }
   ```

That said, this being a one-to-one doesn't really make sense. Tasks are something you generally have multiple of (If only I had only just one task to perform ever!). As a result, this should likely be a one-to-many, which would then require you to change `ApplicationUser` to something like:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public ICollection<UserTask> OwnedUserTasks { get; set; }
   public ICollection<UserTask> ExecutedUserTasks { get; set; }
}
```

Even with that change, the same problem as before exists: you have two relationships to the same entity, so you must add configuration to tell EF how to handle that. Only, now, you'll use `HasMany` instead of `HasOne`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(x => x.OwnedUserTasks)
        .WithOne(x => x.OwnerUser);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(x => x.ExecutedUserTasks)
        .WithOne(x => x.ExecutorUser);
}
```

Finally, it's worth mentioning that you can configure this on either side of the relationship. In other words, you could do `Entity<UserTask>` and then `HasOne(x => x.OwnerUser).WithMany(x => x.OwnedUserTasks)`. It's entirely up to you which way you go.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'UserTask' does not contain a definition for 'OwnerUser' and no extension method 'OwnerUser' accepting a first argument of type 'UserTask' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) UserTaskTest C:\Users\lukas\source\repos\UserTaskTest\UserTaskTest\Data\ApplicationDbContext.cs 24 Active

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'UserTask' does not contain a definition for 'ExecutorUser' and no extension method 'ExecutorUser' accepting a first argument of type 'UserTask' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) UserTaskTest C:\Users\lukas\source\repos\UserTaskTest\UserTaskTest\Data\ApplicationDbContext.cs 28 Active

Comment: EF doesn't recognize OwnerUser and ExecutorUser

Comment: Do you have those properties. This is pretty basic debugging stuff. Please put in a little effort yourself, instead of just coming back with each new exception. Answers here are ultimately a framework to guide you in the right direction, you still need to integrate the solutions into your own code.

Comment: I make small change to:  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(x => x.OwnedUserTasks)
            .WithOne(x => x.OwnerUserID);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
           .HasMany(x => x.ExecutedUserTasks)
          .WithOne(x => x.ExecutorUserID);
}

but I got another error The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined.

Comment: But this is a very simple example and your solution give another errors while compiling the code. sometimes is better not answering than giving "framework solution". I'm beginner so sometimes i need more details.

Comment: And, you'll never grow if you don't take some initiative to figure things out on your own. Stack Overflow is here to help when you're really stuck, but you could have gleamed all this info from the docs, if you had taken the time to read them. Do your best to solve issues yourself, first, and you'll gain knowledge and experience that will help you throughout the rest of your career.